# Выборка из БД возвращает object(mysqli_result)

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Привет. Пишу скрипт чата, сделал для кажого ранга пользователей отдельный вывод сообщений: администратору в диалоге выводятся все сообщения, пользователю и заказчику только те, которые прошли модерацию. Код:

```
    if($user->rank($_SESSION['email']) == "customer")
    {
        $smarty->assign("is_customer","true");
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `customer` = '".cc($_SESSION['email'])."' AND `id` = '".cc($uri[3])."'");
        if($db->num_rows($query) == 0)
        {
            header("Location:".MAIN_URL."/");
        }
        $mess = $db->all_fetch_array($db->query("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `to_work` = '".cc($uri[3])."' AND `to_person` = '0' AND `from` = '".cc($_SESSION['email'])."' AND `checked` = '1'"));
    }
```

Переменная $mess это и есть выбор сообщений.
В конце после всех проверок идет такая конструкция:

```
$smarty->assign("work_inf",$db->fetch_array($mess));
```

Но mysql все время возвращает всякую ересь типа **object(mysqli_result)#17 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(8) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }**. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

```
if($db->num_rows($query) == 0)
{
    header("Location:".MAIN_URL."/");
    die();    
}
```

Возможно после header стоит завершать дальнейшее выполнение.

Comment: @bitrixoid ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Можно попробовать вывести с помощью echo сформированный запрос и отправить его непосредственно СУБД (как вариант, выполнить этот запрос с помощью phpMyAdmin).
Из Вашего вопроса следует, что php возвращает объект результата запроса с нулевым числом строк. По приведённому фрагменту кода понять причину сложно.